# LED Lighting Project: Components for RGB controllable system using cree® Xlamp® Xm-l color leds

Tags: led, rgb

Experience:  Novice, I know not to touch 220v circuits...

Objective:   LED lighting system for exterior trellis with controllable color, using Cree® Xlamp® Xm-l color leds.

Required:  What is the easiest way, and what components in addition to the Cree LED's are needed to control colors?

Assumptions:  Correct transformer is used, correct dimmer is used, 8 of the Cree LED's (or similar) to shown will be used in aluminum heat sink kits like the one shown below.

Any help will be appreciated and especially help related to controlling the Cree's colors.

[image]

Comment: No good. You need a proper LED driver supply for rated voltage DC and current. So include datasheets with V, A specs

Comment: Thanks Tony - I'll pull the specs together for what I'm trying to do, but if I'm understanding things sort of right, we're talking about something like the photo below, that connects to the transformer on one side, and the LED on the other, or something like that?  Looks I edited the driver photo to the original question post.

Comment: Driver 3023?  Output current, 3021-x-x-350, 3023-x-x-350 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 350mA1 Output current, 3021-x-x-500, 3023-x-x-500 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 500mA1 Output current, 3021-x-x-700, 3023-x-x-700 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 700mA1 Outputcurrent,3021-x-x-1000,3023-x-x-1000 .............. ...............1000mA1

Comment: OK, newbie mode. Do you want your lights to be point sources or tight beams or spotlights? Then use some high power LEDs like XML with proper cooling and optics (always think about the optics, it's a very important part to make the final result look good). Do you want your lights to be more diffuse? In this case you can use LED strips. So, first, decide about that.

Comment: Note optics is even more important for RGB. If you use the wrong optic, or its not focused properly, all three/four colors on your LED will have a different beam, making color uneven. Then you need to decide if you want all LEDs with same color and intensity, so one controller for all LEDs, or be able to control each LED individually, or in groups. Which one? Can your LEDs can be wired in series? (this is rare for RGB LEDs, you should show the datasheet). Are they common anode? What power?

Comment: Also you seem to think you can use a wall dimmer (presumably triac) with a RGB controller. I'm really not sure about that. Besides, a wall dimmer has only one knob, no good for RGB. You need something with a remote. I'm using some nice aliexpress controllers in my house, and the remote control is quite user-friendly, but they only support constant voltage LED strips.

Comment: bobflux - eight LED's focused at 18 inches from the wall they will be shining on.  I would like to be able to control each LED, but if it is easier to have one group, I can go that way.

Comment: bobflux -  I tried to find instructions on how to build such a system (examples) but to no good result.  at this point, I understand the idea that each components has to be compatible, I cannot use strip lights, I need 8 individual LED's and it would be really cool to be able to take this offline with someone, so I can explain in a doc, not post frank@lifecraftmedia.com

Comment: Im trying to light the exterior of our garage, that is having a trellis (aluminum 2x12 beams) put across and above the two doors - the led's would be inside the trellis, pointing at the garage wall so flood optics might be required and still at that distance be more spot like.

Comment: are you choosing a dimmer + transformer because it’s free and you already have it? It’s not the best way to control LED current with rectified 12Vac sine. I’ve done this before with 30W on a 300W transformer but you need a 30A bridge diode and a big low ESR cap.

Comment: Tony, I really have no idea what the components should be is the problem.  I know that I want to be able to dim and change colors for the 8 LED's together (assuming series wiring?), and that I'm using the aluminum heat sink shown above.  Beyond that, I have no real idea about the components needed  - just that AC gets trans to DC, constant current is required, so there's something that does that, and a switch to turn the system on, and the LED's that need to be properly wired.  so my little diagram was a first attempt to visualize the system.

Comment: if we're using eight 5v led's, would something like a Mean Well RSP 150 - 5 be overkill for the power?  It has remote on/off, why I would pick it over their 60 w waterproof power unit - the power will be mounted inside the garage and the the length of the wiring will be approximately 280 inches from the power unit to the end of the run.  That 150 watts would also allow me to add another project to it, later.